# how to sort() return json data from API using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

[image]I know this type of question has been answer , but I just cant find the suitable answer for my situation , I am getting json data from api , then I need to put into a select  and i want to sort before.

```
getCurrency(){

        fetch('https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/currencies')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            const fromcurrencySelect = selectid('fromcurrency');
            const tocurrencySelect = selectid('tocurrency');

            var x;
            for (x in data.results) {

                const currencyName = data.results[x].currencyName;
                const currencyID = data.results[x].id  ;

                /*  */
                const option = createEle('option');
                option.value =  currencyID.sort() ;
                append(option, TextNode(currencyName.sort()) );
                append(fromcurrencySelect,option);

                const option2 = createEle('option');
                option2.value =  currencyID ;
                append(option2, TextNode(currencyName) );
                append(tocurrencySelect,option2);


            }
        })
        .catch(error => {  clog(error); })

    }
```

and here is my helper function

```
function clog(message){
    return console.log(message);
}


function selectid(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}


function querysel(element){
    return document.querySelector(element);
}

function append(parent,element){
    return parent.appendChild(element);
}

function createEle(element){
    return document.createElement(element);           
}

function TextNode(element){
    return document.createTextNode(element);  
}
```

I am a very beginner for javascript , sorry for the inconvenience caused , any assistance would be appreciated .

Comment: The helper function seems more of a hindrance than a help to me; it adds extra (unnecessary) lines of code in addition to creating non-standard (and forgettable) names that use a mix of different cases :P

Comment: What's the structure of the returned JSON? Do you have an example?

Comment: https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/currencies
like this , i tried use forEach but got stuck , I have to use for( in ) loop , because this json is complected in my opinion
picture is edited

Comment: I don't understand the question clearly, Do you want to sort the json response according to the keys (EUR, BBD, etc) before using it?

Comment: nitpicking: instead of `var x; for (x in data.results)` why not `for(let x in data.results)`

Comment: @supra28 i want to sort() the currency name alphabetically
so the select option will like
currency start A letter then B , C D, E F like that

Answer (score 0):

You can just write a compare function to sort the objects using a property on the objects like so:

```
data.results.sort(function(a, b){return a.currencyName- b.currencyName});
```

The sort() method on an array accepts a compare function read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)